# Removing item from RecyclerView and inserting it to another position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to remove item from `RecyclerView` inside `onBindViewHolder` using `position`. This position parameter is position of views visible on screen and not actual position of item in `ArrayList`. If I want to remove this item from this position in a list and move it to another part of the `ArrayList` which is not actually visible on screen (onBindViewHolder position is unknown to me) can I actually somehow update this list with `notifyItemSetChanged()` or only way to do it correctly is to call `notifyDataSetChanged())`?

This is somewhat complex `RecyclerView` with multiple Headers and item variations (I`m using 5 ViewHolders inside Adapter). And main purpose of this Adapter is to change positions of items, making copy of them everytime. Its similar to contact list sections.

Simple representation of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct way is

```
list.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
list.add(newposition,item);
notifyItemInserted(newposition);
```

and the postion of `OnBindViewHolder` is the postion of item in your list , thats how you fill the view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
list.removeItemAt(position)
list.addItemAdd(position)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: One question, is there any way how can I get real item position in onBindViewHolder (not position of view) without doing some sort of filtering of whole list to find my item? Because those items are not simple classes. Most of them had really similar parameters. I want to extract real position in list and do this item manipulation outside of adapter. Adapter is there only to show items most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
  list.remove(position);
  list.add(position, item);
  notifyItemChanged(position, item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although previous answers work, I think the method you want to use to notify the adapter is the following:

```
notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition)
```

> Notify any registered observers that the item reflected
>   at fromPosition has been moved to toPosition.

That way you avoid using two methods while getting the animation/transition effect.

Comment: This is good aswell. But sometimes I want to make just copy of item, so notifyItemInserted is used. I will probably create new question about multiitem refresh in recyclerView.